# Upgrade to Mac OS Lion - how to backup Ruby, *SQL, etc?

Tags: sql, ruby, macos, osx-lion, upgrade

last 2 years I am working primary on Macbook Pro with Snow Leopard system and in the following days I want to upgrade to Lion OS X system.
My worries comes from the setup that I currently use on the laptop - I have there installed and configured Ruby, Php, PostgreSQL, MySQL, Heroku-data, etc.
Then also Mail.app (over 12k emails), documents, photo galeries, just everything...

Is there any way to just install the new OS X and preserve my current programs+data+developer tools?
If not, could you give me any tips, how to make the upgrade painless as much as possible?

Up to now, I am not experienced in upgrading OSX system, so I will welcome all advices.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

An OS upgrade on a Mac preserves all your files. The only thing to go with Lion are any PowerPC-dependent apps, as Rosetta is no longer available in 10.7.